# Switch default execution after return statement

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I'm using the following code block, and the bizarre issue that's happening is even though (I've confirmed this with breakpoints) the first case is hit, AND contains a return statement, the `default` is also hit:

```
switch (sortType)
        {
            case RATING:
                return values.get(position - 1).getRating() != values.get(position).getRating();
            case GRAPE:
                return !values.get(position - 1).getGrape().equals(values.get(position).getGrape());
            case REGION:
                return !values.get(position - 1).getRegion().equals(values.get(position).getRegion());
            default:
                return !values.get(position - 1).getGrape().equals(values.get(position).getGrape());
        }
```

When the `default` block is running, the `sortType` is `RATING`. From what I understand, the `return` in the first case should prevent the `default` from getting run. Is that correct?

Comment: are you getting any exception? For example, if getRating returns null. It is likely that the function gives an exception before returning and jumps to default.

Comment: Try making a boolean variable and compute its value and then return that boolean instead of doing computation directly in return. See if boolean variable is set first.

Answer (score 1):

One of the either line is wrong based on the return type:

```
case RATING:
            return values.get(position - 1).getRating() != values.get(position).getRating();
case GRAPE:
            return !values.get(position - 1).getGrape().equals(values.get(position).getGrape());
```

First one is using != and second one is using .equals(). I suppose the second one is correct.

Comment: No I think it's correct. The function that contains the switch needs to be returning a boolean, and getRating() returns an int, and getGrape returns a String.

Comment: @IllegalArgument No, he's not. left side is index - 1. Right side is index. So like array[index - 1] == array[index].

Comment: @workInAFishBowl I tried to replicate this effect but my code is working as expected(the first return gets executed if found else default) maybe you are missing something

Comment: @IllegalArgument I don't know what I even could be missing. This is so annoying.

Comment: Can you reply to my comment on your original post? I would like to know what happens when you try making a boolean variable and compute its value and then return that boolean instead of doing computation directly in return. See if boolean variable is set first.